# How to overlay more than 2 files in r?

Tags: r, raster, terra

We can compute the mean of corresponding layers from 2 stacks like this.

```
library(raster)
s1 <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
s2 <- sqrt(s1)
m4 <- overlay(s1, s2, fun=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))
```

I have several files in a folder:

```
 data<- list.files ("C:data\\", ".nc", full.names = TRUE)
 for (i in 1:length(data)){
     nn=stack(dff[i])
     res=nn[[1:8]]
     ...............}
```

How can I apply the overlay function to all res

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to do this with "terra" (the replacement of "raster"),

Example data

```
library(terra)
s1 <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
s2 <- sqrt(s1)
```

Solutions to get the "parallel" mean with two SpatRasters:

```
mean(s1, s2)

#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 77, 101, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : Cartesian (Meter) 
#source(s)   : memory
#names       :      red,    green,     blue 
#min values  :   0.0000,   0.0000,   0.0000 
#max values  : 135.4844, 135.4844, 135.4844
```

Or like this

```
app(sds(s1, s2), mean)
```

If you have many files (SpatRasters) you can do:

```
f <- system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra")
ff <- rep(f, 5)

s <- sds(ff)
app(s, mean)

# or 
x <- lapply(ff, rast)
do.call(mean, x)

# or
x <- lapply(ff, rast)
app(sds(x), mean)
```

To subset each SpatRaster before the computations, you can do

```
x <- lapply(ff, \(f) rast(f)[[1:2]])
do.call(mean, x)
```

Or (but this is currently broken)

```
s <- sds(ff)
s <- s[, 1:2,drop=FALSE]
app(s, mean)
```

You can, of course, also subset the output with `[[1:2]]`

---

Note that to get the mean of all layers you could do this instead

```
mean(c(s1, s2))
# or
app(c(s1, s2), mean)
```

Comment: Thank the question is how do this for all files in the folder "data", please.

Comment: Sorry, added a bit more

Comment: is `rep(f, 5)` supposed to be used here?

Comment: Thanks, great, before I compute the mean, I need to select 3 layers S[[1:3]] from each file (or stack). How to do this.

Comment: s <- sds(ff), from here how to select layers from 2 to 4?

Comment: now shown for layer 1:2